# template declaration of array and value

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have a function to declare with 2 arguments:

- the first one is an array of dimension 2 that can be `int`, `string` or `bool`
  It is declared for example like this: `int array[2] = {0};`
- the second argument is a value (`int`, `string`, or `bool`)

I'd like to declare an inline template function to match the different types of array. For instance I do this:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
inline void affectParameter(T* array, V value) 
{   
array[0] = value; 
}
```

and in the cpp file:

```
int value(2); 
int[2] array = {0};
affectParameter(array, value);
```

But I'd like to use only one template `T` in order to avoid problem if in the function call `T` isn't an array of `V`.

nb: I can't declare the variable array in another way.

Comment: It's not valid C++ code, this line: `int[2] array = {0};` must be: `int array[2] = {0};`

Comment: int[2] array isn't valid C++ ...

Comment: oups sorry, just a mistype. Corrected.

Comment: @rudy Why not simply use `std::array`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify the declaration of the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use one template parameter `T`:

```
template <typename T>
inline void affectParameter(T* array, T value)
{
   array[0] = value;
}
```

It will perfectly work with your code:

```
int value(2);
int array[2] = { 0 };
affectParameter(array, value);
```

and will fail to compile (as you want) if you do something like:

```
double value(2);
int array[2] = { 0 };
affectParameter(array, value); /* type mismatch here */
```

But also consider to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as they are more safe in their usage and are state of art in C++ programming.

---

If you can't use them you could make your function definition more clear that it needs an classic array, `T array[]` means the same as `T* array` in this case and is not any more safer:

```
template <typename T>
inline void affectParameter(T array[], T value)
{
   array[0] = value;
}
```

---

**Extension with non-type template parameter**

You can make the function typesafe and also index secure if you will use non-type template parameter:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline void affectParameter(T (&array)[N], T value)
{
   /* You can use N here to check size etc. */
   array[0] = value;
}
```

You will call it by:

```
affectParameter(array, value);
```

and will fail if you use for example a pointer or different types for teh arguments.

Comment: Better pass a reference to array, because `T array[]` is exactly the same as `T* array`. It can still bind to any `T*`. A reference to array will not accept pointers to `T`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thank you I added that!

Comment: Also the size can be made a template parameter

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks again didn't thought about that. I added it too...